# Website that accesses USB drive via SDK

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an SDK for a USB device. It includes some installer for .NET and documentation on how to use the classes. The client supposedly wants a web application that can control the USB device (using the classes provided) without installing any software... What am I supposed to do here? It seems I have to jump through a million hoops, learn a bunch of stupid technologies such as silverlight, etc, just because someone doesn't want to download software (yet is willing to do all the things required to get the website to be able to access the USB device???).

What is the quickest way to get this working? Silverlight? ActiveX? WPF? Java Applets? Is there any problem using a java applet from an asp.net mvc application? What will I need to do to even get these technologies to be able to use the USB device via the API?

Comment: Hey Bob - why not update your profile? it looks like you might be back to ask a few more questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as browsers generally run code in a sandbox, there's no real way to get this to work without the user approving something that is installed on their computer (unless you're willing to find some security exploit, which will probably be patched, landing you back at square one).

Find out what they actually mean by "without installing any software" - what are their concerns about this?

IMHO if they're asking people to plug in a USB device, then surely they can expect people to install a driver or utility software.

Comment: Well, they will accept that the user has to click "this website wants to install a plug-in", or whatever. But will not accept users having to double-click an exe..........

Comment: So ClickOnce could be used then? It's a bit of a PITA to get working initially, but Google use it to distribute Chrome, so it can't be all bad ;)

Comment: Well.. they also have Java Applet plugin installed in the web browser. It seems that this would require less work. Well, it comes down to which one will allow USB device access with the least troubles).

Comment: ClickOnce is actually not that hard to setup, but it types everything to Windows, and it also defies the whole use of having a web application.

Comment: @DonCare: The USB API defies the Web app idea, and probably ties it to Windows-only as well.